# mysql syntax error near '' at line 1 at

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i have stumbled on an error which i have spend 3hours trying to fix.
i'm trying to save some data from my server onto my mysql db on my webhost.
i do already have my vps ip set in my remote sql thing.
But i'm stumbling into a mysql syntax error.
Would be very grateful if you can help me,
thanks in advance!

**my console:**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your S
QL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for th
e right syntax to use near '' at line 1
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2941)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1623)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1715)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3243)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1343)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1260)
        at org.dementhium.mysql.hiscores.query(hiscores.java:53)
        at org.dementhium.mysql.hiscores.saveHighScore(hiscores.java:80)
```

my java file:

```
  package org.dementhium.mysql;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.dementhium.model.player.Player;
import org.dementhium.model.player.Skills;
import org.dementhium.model.player.Skills;
import org.dementhium.mysql.DatabaseManager;

/**
 *
 * @author 'Mystic Flow <Steven@rune-server.org>
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class hiscores extends Thread {

     public static final String[] SKILLS = {"Attack", "Defence",
        "Strength", "Constitution", "Ranged", "Prayer", "Magic", "Cooking",
        "Woodcutting", "Fletching", "Fishing", "Firemaking", "Crafting",
        "Smithing", "Mining", "Herblore", "Agility", "Thieving", "Slayer",
        "Farming", "Runecrafting", "Hunter", "Construction", "Summoning",
        "Dungeoneering"
    };



    public static Connection con = null;
    public static Statement stmt;
    public static boolean connectionMade;
    public static void createConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://slash-scape.org/slash756_highsco","slash756_highsco","");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Highscores updated for ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static ResultSet query(String s) throws SQLException {
        try {
            if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(s);
                rs.updateRow();
                return rs;
            } else {
                stmt.executeUpdate(s);
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            destroyConnection();
            createConnection();
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Highscores updated for,hgjhkhkjhkj ");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void destroyConnection() {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
            connectionMade = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static boolean saveHighScore(Player player) {
        try {
            //query("DELETE FROM `highscores` WHERE username = '"+player.getUsername()+"';");
            //query("DELETE FROM `highscores` WHERE username = '"+player.getUsername()+"';");
            System.out.println("Highscores updated for,hgjhkhkjhkj ");
            query("INSERT INTO `highscores` (`username`,`attack_xp`,`defence_xp`,`strength_xp`,`hitpoints_xp`,`ranged_xp`,`prayer_xp`,`magic_xp`,`cooking_xp`,`woodcutting_xp`,`fletching_xp`,`fishing_xp`,`firemaking_xp`,`crafting_xp`,`smithing_xp`,`mining_xp`,`herblore_xp`,`agility_xp`,`thieving_xp`,`slayer_xp`,`farming_xp`,`runecraft_xp`,`hunter_xp`,`construction_xp`,`summoning_xp`,`dungeoneering_xp`,`overall_xp`,`rights`) VALUES ("+player.getUsername()+","+player.getSkills().getXp(0)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(1)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(2)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(3)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(4)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(5)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(6)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(7)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(8)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(9)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(10)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(11)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(12)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(13)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(14)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(15)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(16)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(17)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(18)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(19)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(20)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(21)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(22)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(23)+","+player.getSkills().getXp(24)+","+((player.getSkills().getXp(0)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(1)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(2)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(3)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(4)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(5)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(6)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(7)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(8)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(9)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(10)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(11)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(12)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(13)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(14)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(15)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(16)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(17)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(18)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(19)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(20)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(21)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(22)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(23)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(24)))+","+player.getRights()+";");
            //query("INSERT INTO `skillsoverall` (`playerName`,`lvl`,`xp`, `prestige`) VALUES ('"+player.getUsername()+"',"+(player.getSkills().getLevel(0) + player.getSkills().getLevel(1) + player.getSkills().getLevel(2) + player.getSkills().getLevel(3) + player.getSkills().getLevel(4) + player.getSkills().getLevel(5) + player.getSkills().getLevel(24) + player.getSkills().getLevel(6) + player.getSkills().getLevel(7) + player.getSkills().getLevel(8) + player.getSkills().getLevel(9) + player.getSkills().getLevel(10) + player.getSkills().getLevel(11) + player.getSkills().getLevel(12) + player.getSkills().getLevel(13) + player.getSkills().getLevel(14) + player.getSkills().getLevel(15) + player.getSkills().getLevel(16) + player.getSkills().getLevel(17) + player.getSkills().getLevel(18) + player.getSkills().getLevel(19) + player.getSkills().getLevel(20) + player.getSkills().getLevel(21) + player.getSkills().getLevel(22) + player.getSkills().getLevel(23))+" ,"+((player.getSkills().getXp(0)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(1)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(2)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(3)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(4)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(5)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(6)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(7)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(8)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(9)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(10)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(11)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(12)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(13)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(14)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(15)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(16)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(17)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(18)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(19)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(20)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(21)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(22)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(23)) + (player.getSkills().getXp(24)))+";");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

my MySQL database query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `highscores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rights` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `overall_xp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `attack_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `defence_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `strength_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `constitution_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ranged_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prayer_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `magic_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cooking_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `woodcutting_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fletching_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fishing_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firemaking_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `crafting_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `smithing_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mining_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `herblore_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `agility_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `thieving_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `slayer_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `farming_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `runecrafting_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hunter_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `construction_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `summoning_xp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dungeoneering_xp` int(11) NOT NULL

) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: We're happy to help, but that doesn't involve debugging your code for you.  Synopsize what you have done to attempt to resolve the issue.  That would prevent us from walking down the same path you already have.

Comment: There is a missing character in your query. That's what `the right syntax to use near ''` means -- the parser is facing an empty string `''` because it ran out of tokens.  Print the query you are constructing and the solution should be obvious.  It seems readily apparent that `()+";");` should be `()+");");` but you should not merely patch this insecure and unmaintainable code.  Concatenating strings to build queries is not an acceptable practice. See the "prepared statements" answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are constructing your query incorrectly by not quoting `Strings`. This is only going to be compounded if your Strings have additional quotes in them!

To get around this, use `PreparedStatement`. Not only is it simpler, it's safer and helps prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Basic example:

```
final static String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO highscores (username,attack_xp,defence_xp) values(?,?,?)"; // Etc...
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY);
ps.setString(1, player.getUsername());
ps.setInt(2, player.getAttackXp());
ps.setInt(3, player.getDefenseXp());
// etc.
ps.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect, one of the mistake is `varchar` should be wrapped with `'` you are not doing it, also it is messy and vulnerable so use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead

Comment: so the error comes from the sql query and not from the java file?

Comment: You are passing sql query from Java class and error is there in construction of query, can you print the final query it is trying to execute and run it